# Lubricating Spring Compresor Threads

Tags: tools, struts

I'm getting ready to replace the struts on one of my vehicles using a set of [ampro T70570 coil spring compressors](http://www.amprotools.net/Product_List.aspx?productid=754&partnerid=32&categoryid=5&mode=show):

[image]

I had vaguely remembered reading somewhere that it's a good idea to [oil the threads](http://www.atoolshed.com/instruct/1218r.pdf), and found [more than one reference](http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/pdfImages/9d/9d6be698-cb34-46b6-9b88-4c0e11824b14.pdf) to doing this.

> Before each use inspect, clean and lubricate threads on threaded shaft.

or

> Lubricate threads on spring compressor with engine oil.

Could I use any oil, like WD-40 or a moly grease, or does it really need to be specifically engine oil?

Also, why do the threads need to be lubricated?

My particular tool did not come with any instructions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main reason to lubricate the threads on the coil spring compressor, is to make it a lot easier to turn the screw by hand, since there will be a lot of pressure on the threads.  The lubrication will no doubt stop wear on the threads, but in the end, it makes it easier for you to tighten the tool.  This will also be the reason for ensuring that the threads are clean.

I would suggest a thin oil, but not as thin as WD40.

You could try it without lubrication and then add some to see the difference.

Comment: The threaded rods can also bend under the pressure, so keeping them lubricated could prevent the nuts from ceasing/cross threading. Having said that, @OP is using name brand products, which is a good start. I have used Harbor Freight spring compressors in the past, did not lubricate them, and it was a extremely difficult.